# how to import specified collection data using mongo connector

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am importing data from mongodb 3.4.6 to solr 7.6.0  all of data is imported but i need to import from some specified database to some collections only not all of the data. and i want to get only some specified fields from the collection. how to import in that manner please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of mongo-connector, you can either use the `-n` parameter (pre 2.5.0), or [the `namespaces` configuration setting](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options#namespaces) (2.5.0+):

> `namespaces` Default: Include all namespaces except system and GridFS
>   collections.
>
> NEW in 2.5.0: The namespaces configuration option is used to control
>   how and which MongoDB namespaces are replicated. By default, Mongo
>   Connector will replicate all namespaces except for system and GridFS
>   collections. Namespaces should be given as
>   database_name.collection_name. Each namespace may contain a single
>   wildcard (*) which matches any characters. For example, db_*.foo
>   matches db_bar.foo and db_a.foo.

You tell `mongo-connector` which configuration to use with the `-c` parameter:

```
mongo-connector -c config.json
```

To index into a specific collection, [give the collection name to the `-t` parameter](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr#the-basics):

```
-t http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCore
```

To only index specific fields, [use the `fields` configuration option](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options#fields) or the `-i` command line argument.